# How to respresent and plot data while on loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What I'm trying to to is to simulate the position of two satellites and to determine if they will collide. For that I'm using a Rk4 method. As you can see, in the loop I have the `drawnow` command that adds a point on a 3d graph, after avery iteration. What I'm interested in is to find a way to represent the 3d plot until the condition of collision meets (where I have the message) and also to get the values on the `.txt` file, while in the loop not outside. When I use the return command, and try to plot or to add text, I have an error "vectors must be the same length" and doesn't let me obtain the data. That happens because lets say sat1=1X200 while tspan=1X201. Is there any other command that I could use instead of return or a better solution?

Here is my code:

```
clear; close all; clc;
figure(1);
orbitsat1 = animatedline('Color','r');

msat1 = 124;
msat2 = 234;
Asat1 = 2.2;
Asat2 = 3.2;

sat10(1) = 453322.3616;
sat10(2) = -2346021.219;
sat10(3) = -7894131.349;
sat10(4) = 2142.38067;
sat10(5) = 7487.44895;
sat10(6) = -9864.00872;
sat10 = sat10';

sat20(1) = 543322.3616;
sat20(2) = -3246021.219;
sat20(3) = -8794131.349;
sat20(4) = 1242.38067;
sat20(5) = 4787.44895;
sat20(6) = -8964.00872;
sat20 = sat20';

tspan = 0:200;
secpday = 60*60*24;
a1 = 2018;
la1 = 1;
z1 = 2;
o1 = 12;
m1 = 0;
s1 = 0;
n1 = datenum(a1,la1,z1,o1,m1,s1);

n1 = n1 + tspan/secpday;

[an,luna,zi,ora,min,sec] = datevec(n1);

h = 1;
sat1 = zeros(6, tspan(end)/h);
sat1(:,1) = sat10;

sat2 = zeros(6, tspan(end)/h);
sat2(:,1) = sat20;

for i = 1:tspan(end)/h
    k_1 = simsat1(tspan(i), sat1(:,i), msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_2 = simsat1(tspan(i)+0.5*h, sat1(:,i)+0.5*h*k_1,msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_3 = simsat1(tspan(i)+0.5*h, sat1(:,i)+0.5*h*k_2,  msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_4 = simsat1(tspan(i)+h, sat1(:,i)+k_3*h, msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));

    k_12 = simsat2(tspan(i), sat2(:,i),  msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_22 = simsat2(tspan(i)+0.5*h, sat2(:,i)+0.5*h*k_12,  msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_32 = simsat2(tspan(i)+0.5*h, sat2(:,i)+0.5*h*k_22, msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_42 = simsat2(tspan(i)+h, sat2(:,i)+k_32*h, msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));

    sat2(:,i+1) = sat2(:,i) + (1/6)*(k_12+2*k_22+2*k_32+k_42)*h;
    sat1(:,i+1) = sat1(:,i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;
    addpoints(orbitsat1, sat1(1,i), sat1(2,i), sat1(3,i));
    drawnow update;
    hold off;

    Rorb = sqrt(sum(sat1(1:3,i).^2));
    Rcsc = sqrt(sum(sat2(1:3,i).^2));
    dif = Rorb-Rcsc;

    if (dif >0.5e10 && dif < 2e5) && i>350
        Message = sprintf('Data:\nan:%d\nluna:%d\nzi:%d\nora:%d\nminut:%d\nsecunda:%d',an(i),luna(i),zi(i),ora(i),min(i),sec(i));
        msgbox(Message)
        msgbox('Coliziune!','Coliziune','warn',Message);
        return
    end
end

Pozx = sat1(1,:);
Pozy = sat1(2,:);
Pozz = sat1(3,:);

Tbody = [an luna zi ora min sec Pozx Pozy Pozz]';
twobody = fopen('nobody.txt','w');
fprintf(twobody,'Rezultate Twobody (metri) \n\n');
fprintf(twobody,'  An  luna  zi   ora min sec            pozitia pe  x     pozitia pe  y      pozitia pe  z       viteza pe  x    viteza pe  y    viteza pe  z\n\n');
fprintf(twobody,'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n%6d-%3d-%3d\t%3d:%3d:%3d\t\t\t\t%12.6f\t%12.6f\t\t%12.6f\t\t%12.6f\t%\n',Tbody);
fclose(twobody);
```

where simsat1

```
function sat1prim = simsat1(t,sat1,msat1,Asat1,vit)
miu = 398600.4418e9;
magn = sum(sat1(1:3).^2)^(3/2);
sat1prim = zeros(6,1);
sat1prim(1:3) = sat1(4:6);
sat1prim(4:6) = -miu.*sat1(1:3)./magn;
end
```

and  simsat2

```
function sat2prim = simsat2(t,sat2,msat2,Asat2,vit)
miu = 398600.4418e9;
magn = sum(sat2(1:3).^2)^(3/2);
sat2prim = zeros(6,1);
sat2prim(1:3) = sat2(4:6);
sat2prim(4:6) = -miu.*sat2(1:3)./magn;
end
```

Comment: If they're only 1 element different, why not just exclude the final `tspan` value for plotting?

Comment: That would work only in case of a collision , but if the satellites won t collide over a period of time that wouldn't be correct. Thats because sat1=201( in the case without collision) and tspan=201; you propouse tspan=tspan-1; and I would get the same error.

Comment: Your code example does not work. It's missing `secundePeZi`, `msat1`, `Asat1` and then it throws an error when indexing `simsat1`. There may be error afterwards but I gave up trying by this point. Do the following; add `close all; clear; clc;` line at the very top of your code. Then make sure it runs and update your question. I'm guessing this code worked for you because you had all of these variables already in your workspace. To avoid this type of 'crosstalk' between the scripts I'd recommend always putting the `close all; clear; clc;` at the beginning of every piece of code.

Comment: You are wright. I've just uptade the code with A,m, and the functions.

Comment: Three things: 1. I don't understand your collision condition: `dif >0.5*10^10 && dif < 2*10^5) && i>350`. How can `dif` be simultaneously bigger than 5e9 and smaller than 2e5 ?? Are you sure you've got your `<>` signs correct. Also; are you sure that on the line before it shouldn't say `dif = abs(Rorb-Rcsc);`? 2. Your code as supplied does not actually produce the collision you speak of (nor the error on that matter). 3. Your functions take 5 input arguments but use only one - the `sat1` and `sat2`'s. The others are apparently superfluous but are used and varied in your code...(?)

Comment: The first one is  obviously an abberation. I've just tried to use it just to see if the collision detector works . You should try if :sat1(1,i)>sat2(1,i) , for example.Indeed the signs are not correct.For the sat1 , sat2 I will complete with some perturbations, that's why I needed the extra terms.

Comment: Ok; see my answer. Also; for the future; I'd make sure your code example reproduces the problem easilly and add comments. I am not sure what is stackoverflow's policy on languages (admins??) but I dont think I'm wrong to say you're overwehlmingly more likely to get an answer to your question when your code is in english. I'd reccomend a quick read of [posting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright; If I understand correctly this should be what you want.

I've moved the `Tbody` variable inside of the ‘for’ loop and I'm writing each timestep to the file as it happens. Also, the keyword you were searching for is `break`, not `return`. `break` just breaks you out of the current for or while loop (up only one level) while `return` returns the control to the invoking function.

I've changed slightly the way to initialise the time vector to make it more clear. Your problem with "sat1=1X200 while tspan=1X201" came from the fact that your `tspan = 0:200` which is **201** points, while `tpsan(end)` value is only **200**. This is fine and makes sense as you're including your initial position in your vectors. Basically make sure all of them have the right number of points. I've done this by defining a timestep `dt=1` hour and then number of timesteps `nt=200`. This way my time vector becomes `tspan = 0:nt*dt` and it will have `nt+1` points. I can then iterate `for i = 1:(nt-1)` just like you did.

I've added comments throughout which I'd encourage you to do too in your code. Anyway; here it is:

```
clear; close all; clc;
warning('on'); % Turn on warnings (Because they may be off)

figure(1);
orbitsat1 = animatedline('Color','r');

%% Initial conditions
msat1 = 124; msat2 = 234; Asat1 = 2.2; Asat2 = 3.2;

% Initialise satellites
sat10 = [453322.3616 -2346021.219 -7894131.349 2142.38067 7487.44895 -9864.00872];
sat20 = [543322.3616 -3246021.219 -8794131.349 1242.38067 4787.44895 -8964.00872];

dt = 1; % On hour timestep
nt = 200; % Number of timesteps
tspan = (0:nt)*dt; % Time from 0 to 200 timesteps in hours

% Make the time vectors
n1 = datenum(2018,1,2,12,0,0); % Starting point (serial date number in days)
n1 = n1 + tspan/24; % Timespan from hours -> days
[an,luna,zi,ora,min,sec] = datevec(n1);

%% Initialise containers
% Satelites
% nt+1 points because (:,1) is the initial condition
sat1 = zeros(6,nt+1); sat1(:,1) = sat10;
sat2 = zeros(6,nt+1); sat2(:,1) = sat20;

% Initialise Tbody here
Tbody = zeros(9,nt+1); Tbody(1:6,:) = [an; luna; zi; ora; min; sec];

%% Open the file
f_twobody = fopen('nobody.txt','w');
fprintf2(f_twobody,'Rezultate Twobody (metri)\n');
fprintf2(f_twobody,'Numar\tAn\tluna\tzi\tora\tmin\tsec\tpozitia_pe_x\tpozitia_pe_y\tpozitia_pe_z\n');
fprintf2(f_twobody,'%06d\t%6d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%12.6f\t%12.6f\t%12.6f\n',0,Tbody(:,1));

%% Go though all the timesteps
for i = 1:(nt-1)
    % Calculate timestep
    k_1 = simsat1(tspan(i), sat1(:,i), msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_2 = simsat1(tspan(i)+0.5*dt, sat1(:,i)+0.5*dt*k_1,msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_3 = simsat1(tspan(i)+0.5*dt, sat1(:,i)+0.5*dt*k_2,  msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));
    k_4 = simsat1(tspan(i)+dt, sat1(:,i)+k_3*dt, msat1, Asat1, sat1(4:6,i));

    k_12 = simsat2(tspan(i), sat2(:,i),  msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_22 = simsat2(tspan(i)+0.5*dt, sat2(:,i)+0.5*dt*k_12,  msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_32 = simsat2(tspan(i)+0.5*dt, sat2(:,i)+0.5*dt*k_22, msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));
    k_42 = simsat2(tspan(i)+dt, sat2(:,i)+k_32*dt, msat2, Asat2, sat2(4:6,i));

    sat2(:,i+1) = sat2(:,i) + (1/6)*(k_12+2*k_22+2*k_32+k_42)*dt;
    sat1(:,i+1) = sat1(:,i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*dt;

    % Put the calculated positions into Tbody
    Tbody(7:9,i+1) = [sat1(1,i+1) sat1(2,i+1) sat1(3,i+1)]';

    % Write next line to the file
    fprintf2(f_twobody,'%06d\t%6d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%12.6f\t%12.6f\t%12.6f\n',i,Tbody(:,i+1));

    % Update plot
    addpoints(orbitsat1, sat1(1,i), sat1(2,i), sat1(3,i));
    drawnow update; hold off;

    % Check for collision
    Rorb = sqrt(sum(sat1(1:3,i+1).^2));
    Rcsc = sqrt(sum(sat2(1:3,i+1).^2));
    dif = abs(Rorb-Rcsc);
    %if (dif >0.5e10 && dif < 2e5) && i>350
    if sat1(1,i)>sat2(1,i) % Some kindof collision condition
        warning('Coliziune! %d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d',Tbody(1:6,i+1));
        fprintf(f_twobody,'Coliziune!\n');
        break % Break out of the for loop (use this instead of 'return')
    end
end

fclose(f_twobody); % Close the file
```

---

```
function sat1prim = simsat1(t,sat1,msat1,Asat1,vit)
miu = 398600.4418e9;
magn = sum(sat1(1:3).^2)^(3/2);
sat1prim = zeros(6,1);
sat1prim(1:3) = sat1(4:6);
sat1prim(4:6) = -miu.*sat1(1:3)./magn;
end
```

---

```
function sat2prim = simsat2(t,sat2,msat2,Asat2,vit)
miu = 398600.4418e9;
magn = sum(sat2(1:3).^2)^(3/2);
sat2prim = zeros(6,1);
sat2prim(1:3) = sat2(4:6);
sat2prim(4:6) = -miu.*sat2(1:3)./magn;
end
```

---

```
function fprintf2(f,varargin)
% Write both to stdout (console) and file
fprintf(varargin{:}); fprintf(f,varargin{:});
end
```

Comment: That works very good. But what if I want to integrate for every second, assuming Tspan=200 seconds?Also,  I see in the .txt file that  sec(second) are from are sec+24s, and that it starts from 0 at the first timestep.Is there a way to put instead of 0 at first step the values for init cond and the seconds sec=sec+1?

Comment: I'm not sure whether your algorithm will work for that, but in principle you could just set `dt = 1/3600` hours (i.e. 1s). As to the 'sec' entry in the file, it is what's generated by `datevec`. The first entry in the file it literally the initial conditions (there is an `fprintf` putting it there just before the loop). I've also noticed there were some errors in my code (I've assumed `datevec` has units of seconds but it in fact has units of days. Also brackets are hard...) so I've corrected that (see code above). Give it a go now. The entries in .txt should make more sense.